# Rsocket-java stream: How to replace/update the JWT token within Flux.retryWhen(...)?

Tags: spring-boot, rsocket, rsocket-java, spring-rsocket

Given the rsocket client retrieving data from server using stream semantic, I would like to utilize `Flux.retryWhen(retryBackoffSpec)` mechanizm to reconnect in case connection is lost. Streaming endpoint on server requires valid JWT tokens to be provided.

Initial connection works fine, however I'm having problems during reconnection:

- if the reconnection happens while the JWT token is still valid the process is successful,
- if the reconnection happens after JWT expired, it's failing with:

`last failure={RejectedSetupException (0x3): Jwt expired at 2022-12-13T10:26:39Z}` error

I was not able to find a way to replace a JWT token send as metadata to streaming endpoint **before retry**
is performed. In my attempt, original JWT token (expired one) sent during initial request is used, which of course causes the error:

```
this.rSocketRequester
        .route("stream")
        .metadata(getAccessToken(), AUTHENTICATION)
        .data(streamRequest)
        .retrieveFlux(GenericRecord.class)
        .retryWhen(retryBackoffSpec); // ?? how to replace the JWT token ??
```

I'm looking for a way to replace the metadata send during the retry with newly obtained JWT token (via `getAccessToken()` method).

**Client**

Connection initialization:

```
private static final MimeType AUTHENTICATION = MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeType(WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_AUTHENTICATION.getString());

public void connect() {
    final SocketAcceptor responder = RSocketMessageHandler.responder(rSocketStrategies, new ClientHandler());

    //@formatter:off
    retryBackoffSpec = Retry
            .fixedDelay(10, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .doBeforeRetry(signal -> log.warn("Connecting retry: {}", signal));

    final RSocketRequester.Builder rSocketRequesterTpl = rSocketRequesterBuilder
            .setupRoute("subscriber")
            .setupData(CLIENT_ID)
            .rsocketStrategies(builder -> {
                builder.encoders(encoders -> {
                    encoders.add(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEncoder());
                });
            })
            .rsocketConnector(connector -> {
                connector.acceptor(responder);
                connector.reconnect(retryBackoffSpec);
            });
    //@formatter:on

    this.rSocketRequester = rSocketRequesterTpl.tcp("localhost", 7000);
}
```

Stream subscription:

```
public void stream(final MessageCallback callback, final StreamRequest streamRequest) {
    final Flux<GenericRecord> streamFlux = this.rSocketRequester
            .route("stream")
            .metadata(getAccessToken(), AUTHENTICATION)
            .data(streamRequest)
            .retrieveFlux(GenericRecord.class)
            .retryWhen(retryBackoffSpec); // ?? how to replace the JWT token ??

    streamFlux.publishOn(scheduler).subscribe(m -> callback.doOnMessage(m), t -> callback.doOnError(t));
}
```

**Server controller**

```
    @ConnectMapping("subscriber")
    void connectSubscriber(final RSocketRequester requester, @Payload final String client) {
    // removed for clarity
    }


@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
@MessageMapping({ "stream" })
Flux<StreamMessage > stream(@AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "@authenticationConverter.convert(#this)") final JwtAuthenticationToken user,
        @Payload(required = false) StreamRequest streamRequest) {
        return Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100)).map(i -> {
            final StreamMessage message = new StreamMessage();
            message.setIndex(i);
            return message;
        });
}
```

**Relevant dependencies**:

```
spring-boot-starter-parent 2.7.6
rsocket-core 1.1.3
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `metadata()` method:

> The metadata value be a concrete value or any producer of a single value that can be adapted to a Publisher via ReactiveAdapterRegistry.

So, you can provide updated JWT token like this:

```
this.rSocketRequester
    .route("stream")
    .metadata(Mono.fromSupplier(this::getAccessToken), AUTHENTICATION)
    .data(streamRequest)
    .retrieveFlux(GenericRecord.class)
    .retryWhen(retryBackoffSpec);
```